# Controller which is delegate of UITextField does not respond to delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I got a textField declared as an outlet, it is correctly connected via the storyboard:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addBillEventName;
```

I also have set the delegate of the UITextfield via code and via the storyboard, code:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.addBillEventName setDelegate:self];
}
```

So you would expect that methods like this:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.addBillEventName setDelegate:self];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch end controller");
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     NSLog(@"Touch end controller");
}
```

Would trigger, but they don't get triggered. Weird is that `charactersInRange` does work.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: `touchesBegan:` and `touchesEnded:` are not delegate methods of a `UITextfield`

Comment: Please referto the UITextFieldDelegate here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: To implement touch detection on a UITextField, you can use UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: Pff. Indeed, replaced `touchesBegan` with `textFieldDidBeginEditting` and it works -.-. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Of course directly a minus one. In my opinion, if this helps me solving a problem which I spent hours on you don't do that. But that's  my opinion.